# How to shift a multiple rows into columns

Tags: r

Here is my data:

```
structure(list(gender = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male"
), bins = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6"), cases = c(1L, 23L, 28L, 28L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 119L, 77L, 
79L, 24L, 0L), employees = c(1L, 15L, 12L, 11L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 48L, 
45L, 38L, 16L, 0L), headcount = c(7L, 180L, 145L, 117L, 38L, 
1L, 37L, 797L, 1167L, 945L, 785L, 61L), propC = c(14.2857142857143, 
12.7777777777778, 19.3103448275862, 23.9316239316239, 5.26315789473684, 
100, 5.40540540540541, 14.930991217064, 6.5981148243359, 8.35978835978836, 
3.05732484076433, 0), propE = c(14.2857142857143, 8.33333333333333, 
8.27586206896552, 9.4017094017094, 5.26315789473684, 100, 5.40540540540541, 
6.02258469259724, 3.8560411311054, 4.02116402116402, 2.03821656050955, 
0)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

I was wondering how could I shift all rows containing Male/ Female to the right so the first row looks something like this:

```
Female 1 1 1 7 14.285714 14.28571 Male 1 2 2 37 5.405405 5.40540
```

Comment: `Reduce(cbind, split(d, d$gender))`

Comment: exactly what I needed thank you, also is there an easy way to rename the columns since there will be duplicate column names?

Comment: The `colnames()` function allow you to rename the columns